# Converter NodeList em String(?) / Capturando valores de Checkbox (javascript)

Tags: javascript, checkbox

estou criando um formulário e gostaria de capturar valores dele, e ao submeter renderizo ele na tela.

Entretanto um dos campos é de checkbox e o usuário pode escolher mais de uma opção, como utilizei o document.queryselectorAlll ele me retorna uma nodeList. E (como sou iniciante) não estou conseguindo converter esses valores em string ou capturar esses valores.

Como posso fazer? Preciso capturar esse valor (ou valores) dessa nodeList. Estou tentando a partir do código abaixo:

```
document.querySelector('.formcadastro').addEventListener('submit', function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var campos = [
        document.querySelector('#nome-completo'),
        document.querySelector('input[name="generos"]:checked'),
        document.querySelector('#nascimento'),
        document.querySelector('#cpf'),
        document.querySelector('#rg'),
        document.querySelector('#carga'),
        document.querySelector('#salario'),
        document.querySelector('#predio'),
        document.querySelectorAll('input[name="transporte"]:checked')
    
    ]

    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    campos.forEach(function(campo){

        var td = document.createElement('td');

        td.textContent = campo.value;
        tr.appendChild(td);
        
    });

    tbody.appendChild(tr);
    console.log(campos);
    
});
```

que retorna:

```
(9) [input#nome-completo.form-control, input#feminino.form-check-input, input#nascimento.form-control, input#cpf.form-control, input#rg.form-control, input#carga.form-control, input#salario.form-control, input#predio.form-control, NodeList(1)]

0: input#nome-completo.form-control
1: input#feminino.form-check-input
2: input#nascimento.form-control
3: input#cpf.form-control
4: input#rg.form-control
5: input#carga.form-control
6: input#salario.form-control
7: input#predio.form-control
8: NodeList(1)
0: input#bhbus.form-check-input
length: 1
__proto__: NodeList
length: 9
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: e como espera os dados? uma lista por exemplo "1, 3, 4"?  ou array [1, 3, 4]?

Comment: Isso, como uma lista.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode "espalhar" (spread) objetos iteráveis como *Arrays* e *NodeLists* com o operador `...`.

Quando você utiliza esse operador, cada item do objeto iterável é passado como uma variável diferente para uma função, ou para uma inicialização de um array, como é o seu caso.

Acredito que o que você quer fazer pode ser obtido dessa forma:

```
var campos = [
    document.querySelector('#nome-completo'),
    document.querySelector('input[name="generos"]:checked'),
    document.querySelector('#nascimento'),
    document.querySelector('#cpf'),
    document.querySelector('#rg'),
    document.querySelector('#carga'),
    document.querySelector('#salario'),
    document.querySelector('#predio'),
    ...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="transporte"]:checked')
]
```